# TStream Read single byte

Tags: delphi

I want to read byte by byte with a TStream (streamIn) or any stream from cache file.

I don' t know Streams well, actually i want to read cache file but byte by byte.
When this "read" function called from another class it must be read next byte in cache file. But TStream has no "readbyte" method.

```
function TStringInputStream.read : Integer;
begin
if not back then 
   lastByte:= streamIn.ReadByte -> ???
back:= false;
Result:= lastByte;
end;

function TStringInputStream.readLine: String;
var
  c     : Integer;
  ns    : Boolean;
  endd  : Boolean;
  res   : String;
begin
  ns:= True;
  endd:= False;

  while not endd do
  begin
    c:= read;
    if (c = -1) and (ns) then
    begin
      Result:= '';
      Exit;
    end;
    ns:= false;

    if (c = LF) or (c = -1) then
      endd:= true
    else if c = CR then
    begin
      if read <> LF then
        rewind;
      endd:= true;
    end
    else
      res:= IntToStr(c);
  end;

  Result:= res;
end;
```

Comment: `function TStreamHelper.ReadByte: Byte; begin ReadBuffer(Result, SizeOf(Result)); end;` e.g., if you were having a `TStream` helper, or use e.g. the `TBinaryReader`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`ReadBuffer`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStream.ReadBuffer) to read a single byte.

```
var
  B: Byte;
....
Stream.ReadBuffer(B, SizeOf(B));
```

Or if you use XE3 or later you can use [`ReadData`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStream.ReadData).

```
Stream.ReadData(B);
```

Comment: streamIn.ReadBuffer(B, SizeOf(B));
  lastByte:= B; is that true?